# Visual Studio - Solution Explorer - Move Filters Up/Down

Tags: filter

It must be a dumb question, but I still can't find the answer on Google after aprox. an hour of searching. My current project looks like this:

```
[my project]:
  Header Files
  Resources
  Source Files
```

I want filters to be ordered this way:

```
[my project]:
  Resources
  Header Files
  Source Files
```

How do I move Resources filter up?

Answer (score 0):

The solution explorer automatically sorts alphabetically.

There is currently no real "simple" solution but you can have a workaround by adding a letter prefix to the project.  Personally I wouldn't do this, but if you really **HAVE** to have it in a specific order, this is one way of doing it.

Prefix your project with A, B, C, D.  Using your example...

Solution Explorer:

```
A.Resources
B.Header Files
C.SourceFiles
```